# when i try to write and read above 255 in EEPROM it shows some unwanted values

Tags: arduino-uno

hai  i have am two buttons. when i press the first button i want to increase value of count variable. And i want to store the count value to the EEPROM for the use of power cut .after power cut i want to start the system with the previous stored count value. in my case when the count value is above 255 during power cut it will start with 0 or other some unwanted values..i want to store nearly 5000 records(1 to 5000 numbers) per day.my problem is above 255 during power cut time .how can i fix this problem.

hai  i have am two buttons. when i press the first button i want to increase value of count variable. And i want to store the count value to the EEPROM for the use of power cut .after power cut i want to start the system with the previous stored count value. in my case when the count value is above 255 during power cut it will start with 0 or other some unwanted values..i want to store nearly 5000 records(1 to 5000 numbers) per day.my problem is above 255 during power cut time .how can i fix this problem.

type here

```
const int BUTTON2 = 2;
//const int BUZZER = 4;
int lastState1 = LOW;  // the previous state from the input pin
int currentState1;     // the current reading from the input pin
unsigned long pressedTime1  = 0;
unsigned long releasedTime1 = 0;
const int SHORT_PRESS_TIME1 = 5000;
int count = 0,z = 0,p = 0;int ledState; 
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
File myFile;
LiquidCrystal lcd(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10); 
void configmode();
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BUTTON1, INPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON2, INPUT);
  //pinMode(BUZZER, OUTPUT);
  //digitalWrite(BUZZER, LOW);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  count = EEPROM.read(0);
     lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("NUMBER OF ENTRY");
        lcd.setCursor(7,1);
        lcd.print(count);delay(100);

}

void loop() {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("NUMBER OF ENTRY");
        lcd.setCursor(7,1);
        lcd.print(count);delay(100);
currentState1 = digitalRead(BUTTON1);
if(lastState1 == LOW && currentState1 == HIGH)        // button is pressed
pressedTime1 = millis();
else if(lastState1 == HIGH && currentState1 == LOW) { // button is released
releasedTime1 = millis();
long pressDuration1 = releasedTime1 - pressedTime1;
   if( pressDuration1 < SHORT_PRESS_TIME1 )
    {
        count = count+1;
        //uint8_t idx = count;
        //EEPROM.update(0, idx);
        EEPROM.update(0, count);
}
    
    else                                        
    {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Config mode....");
    delay(700);
    configmode();
    }
 }
 lastState1 = currentState1;
  if(count > 0)
  {
   p = count % z;
    if(p == 0)
    {
//digitalWrite(BUZZER, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
  //    digitalWrite(BUZZER, LOW);
    }
  }}

  void configmode()
{
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Config value...");         //notic semicondu nrf   esp32 bl2000 
    lcd.setCursor(7,1);
    lcd.print(z);
    delay(500);
    while (true) {
      int x,y;
       x = digitalRead(BUTTON1);
      y = digitalRead(BUTTON2);
      if(x == HIGH)
      {
        
        z = z+1;     
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Config value...");         //notic semicondu nrf   esp32 bl2000 
        lcd.setCursor(7,1);
        lcd.print(z);
        delay(500);
        if(z == 50)
        {
         z = 0;           
        }
      }
      else 
      {
        
      }

     if( y == HIGH )
    {
 
          count = 0;
       lcd.setCursor(0,0);
       lcd.print("EXIT CONFIG..."); delay(5000);
       lcd.clear();
    return;             
    }

     } }
```

Comment: one EEPROM location can store one byte. that has 8-bits so 11111111 binary is maximum. that is 255 in decimal

Comment: Can you please use correct spelling and capitalization? It is really distracting.

Comment: Thanks yuraj,Yes I studied EEPROM can store 8 bit .is there any possibilities for split the data in more then one  memory location.